# Disable click in other divs if one has been clicked already

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

This is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2ajo5jdx/

If you click on link-b a div fade-in,now if you click on link-c another div fadeIn too.I don't want more than one div at the same time.I want to disable click on link-c if link-b has been clicked already.

Is there a simple way?Thank you.

```
$('.b').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.a-div').fadeOut( 400, function(){
        $('.b-div').addClass('active');
        $('.b-div').fadeIn(400);         
    });
});
$('.c').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.a-div').fadeOut( 400, function(){
        $('.c-div').addClass('active');
        $('.c-div').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add almost nothing to your code, you could use a flag, set it to true on each click in a link and to false on close

```
var some_link_opened = false;

$('.b').on("click", function(e) {
    if (some_link_opened) return;
    some_link_opened = true;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.a-div').fadeOut( 400, function(){
        $('.b-div').addClass('active');
        $('.b-div').fadeIn(400);         
    });
});

$('.x').on("click", function(e) {
    some_link_opened = false;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.active').fadeOut( 400, function(){
        $('this').removeClass('active');
        $('.a-div').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that what you mean, but if you want to show just one div every time you can use the following solutio based on `active` class.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
  $('.b').on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').fadeOut( 400, function(){
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.b-div').addClass('active');
            $('.b-div').fadeIn(400);         
        });
    });
    $('.c').on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').fadeOut( 400, function(){
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.c-div').addClass('active');
            $('.c-div').fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
    
     $('.x').on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').fadeOut( 400, function(){
            $('this').removeClass('active');
            $('.a-div').fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
```

```css
.b-div,.c-div{
  
  display:none;
}

.x {
  color:red;
}

.b,.c,.x{
  
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="b">link-b</a>
<a class="c">link-c</a>
<a class="x">x</a>

<div class="a-div active">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="b-div">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
<div class="c-div">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
```